# How do I enable oganization ID logins in my AADB2C application?

Tags: identity, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-account

I have followed the instructions on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-msa-idp?tabs=applications) to add the ability to sign up / log in to my application using a Microsoft Account.  Personal accounts seem to work fine, but organizational IDs do not.  And if I type in an email address that is both an organizational ID as well as a personal account, at no point am I prompted to choose "Work or school account" vs. "Personal account".  When I use the same email to log into Azure, I am prompted to pick one.

The configuration instructions talk specifically about enabling "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)." and I have confirmed that this option is set properly in my registered application.

Is there something else I need to do to enable sign up and log in with organizational IDs in my AADB2C application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you registered an app with the type is **Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox, Outlook.com)**, it doesn't mean you have enabled sign-in for users from an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) organization.

The configuration in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-msa-idp?tabs=applications) is only for MSA. You define the account as a claims provider that Azure AD B2C can communicate with through an endpoint [by adding a claims provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-setup-msa-idp?tabs=applications#add-a-claims-provider).

If you want to enable sign-in for Azure AD users, you should [define Azure AD as a claims provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom?tabs=applications#add-a-claims-provider).

You should finish the configuration on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom?tabs=applications).

Comment: Thanks Allen.  I had looked at the articles you reference at the bottom of your response but they seem to be about enabling sign-in for a specific Azure AD tenant (e.g. Contoso).  Assuming I'm reading that correctly, that's not the scenario I'm trying to enable.  I would like to make it possible for anyone with an Org ID to sign in--not just people in a specific Azure AD.  Is this sort of thing possible with Azure AD B2C?

Comment: Dug a little deeper and found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-commonaad-custom?tabs=applications) which is about enabling sign-in for multi-tenant Azure AD.  Once I set ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes to allow all Azure AD users then the scenario I am working on seems to work as expected.

We were really hoping that the experience for MSA and OrgID would be unified as you see when you log into the Azure Portal, but we can live with two different sign-in options.

Comment: @AndrewMiller That's correct. I didn't notice you are looking for a method which enables sign-in for multi-tenant Azure AD. You have found the correct article:)